# Vigenere Cipher Key Security

Tags: cryptography

**Example**

Key 1: EEEE

Key 2: ERTY

What are the advantages of using key 2 over key 1 and why?

Comment: Do you know how the cipher works?

Comment: I have only learnt the basics of it so i'm sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Test out examples of plaintexts against each of these keys.  What do you notice?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used the key EEEE, the cipher would not be a Vigenère.  It would degenerate into an extremely weak [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).  With the key ERTY, you would get a genuine Vigenère cipher of period 4.  While this is still very weak, breaking it nevertheless does require a little more work than a Caesar cipher does.